# J2ME nextFrame() Problems

Tags: animation, frame, sprite

I have the code in keyStates:-

```
private void actOnKeyStates(ink k) {

/* Other Key States (UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT) */

if ((k & FIRE_PRESSED) !=0)
    boxer.nextFrame();
}
```

We are trying to use the update() function to produce the sprite animation sheet (which is 6 frames long).

Can anyone please help with how this could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used Java Mobile before but this could help?

```
if ((k & FIRE_PRESSED) !=0)
    boxer.nextFrame();
    boxerActive = true;
}
```

have the update function then play the animation when it is true.

Comment: I have tried that, but it still doesn't seem to want to work.